# Upload file from safari using file object stored in indexed db

Tags: indexeddb

I want to upload image from file objects that stored in indexed db. When I tested in Chrome, it works well. But in pc and mobile safari it doesn't work. I checked console log before upload it. I can observe file object and it can be transformed to base64 data url as well. But not included in api request body. FormData is normal but api request data has empty file content.

Comment: A possible workaround that comes to mind would be to clone the file: `new File( [ await file_from_IDB.arrayBuffer() ], file_from_IDB.name )`.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you more your comment. Clone blob was the answer for this case.

```const fileData = filteredFiles.slice(0, 10).map((file) => {
    const blob = file.slice();
    return new File([blob], file.name, { type: file.type });
});```

Comment: In mobile safari clone blob was not work, file -> base 64 -> file process works well. Finally I decided to do not use indexed db because of its storage limit

Comment: What storage limit? indexedDB is one of the less limited storage we have in a browser. Also, in my first comment I told you to clone that file using the `.arrayBuffer()` method, it will take a lot less memory than through the data URL.